# Best way of managing SSL on production and staging sites

Tags: iis, ssl

I'm using II7 to host my production sites as well as my staging sites. I want my staging sites to as closely mimic the functionality of my production sites as possible. However I run into problems when I try to enable SSL on my staging sites because I cant bind the "https" of my staging site to the same IP address as the production site.

Does this mean I need a separate IP addresses for my staging and production sites when using SSL?

Or is there a better and more economical way to deal with this?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. What kind of SSL do you have (if it's public site can you pop in the url so I can have a look myself). 2.Are your staging and production sites on the same web server?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for tackling this.

1. Get 2 certs.  One for staging.yourdomain.com and your existing one for www.yourdomain.com.  Then at any time you can test against either without any trickery.
2. Or you can use the same cert for both and just live with the warning on staging.yourdomain.com since it's for testing only.
3. Use the same cert and domain name for both if you want to have even the domain name identical during testing.  You can achieve this by using a hosts entry (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) on your testing machine that points to a 2nd IP address on your server.  Just swap your hosts file in and out to switch between production and staging.
4. You can consider a reverse proxy like ARR to make the decision on production or staging instead of a hosts file. (not as easy if that's the only purpose for it though)

Here are a couple videos I put together on SSL that are semi-related, in case that helps. ([SSL Bindings issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/02/05/the-ssl-bindings-issue-web-pro-week-6-of-52.aspx) and [SSL in IIS7](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/02/12/setting-host-headers-for-ssl-sites-in-iis-week-7-of-52.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Get a free cert from startssl for your staging site, if cost is an issue.  You'll need two IPs or your staging site will need to listen on different ports.

If staging and prod are on the same server, you could also take advantage of SSL Host Headers in IIS7 (but I have no real world experience with that kind of config so I don't know how well it works).  Couple SSL Host Headers with the free cert from startSSL and I think you'd be good.